Problem with asymptotic behavior of metric
In the Hamiltonian description of asymptotically flat spacetimes, the metric should deviate at infinity from the flat metric by terms of order 1/r
$$g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + \frac{\overline{h}_{ij}}{r} + \mathcal{O}(r^{-2})$$
where $h_{ij}$ only depends on the angles. There are also conditions on the conjugate momenta and some parity conditions.
I would expect then that if I solve the linearized equations of motion on Minkowski background in spherical coordinates, i.e. $$ds^2 = - dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 d \Omega^2$$ the spatial components would behave as $\mathcal{O}(r^{-1})$. However when I did the calculations, I found that the radial function of component $h_{rr}$, is equal to $r Q(r)$, where $Q(r)$ satisfies the Regge-Wheeler equation with $M=0$, namely
$$ \frac{d^2 Q(r)}{dr^2}+ \left( \omega^2 - \frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{r^2} \right)Q(r) = 0$$
which seemed reasonable. ($\ell$ are the numbers associated with the angular momentum)
However the solutions of this function are given by
$$Q(r) = A \sqrt{r} j_\ell(\omega r) + B \sqrt{r}y_\ell (\omega r)$$
where $j_\ell$ and $y_\ell$ are Bessel functions and $A,B$ constants. Then I set $B=0$ since $y_\ell$ diverges at the origin.
My problem is that for large values of $r$ I know that $j_\ell \sim r^{-1/2}$ implying that $Q(r) \sim A$ for large values of $r$. Which implies that $h_{rr} \sim \mathcal{O}(r)$ for large values of $r$.
I do not understand how to reconcile this with the Regge-Teitelboim boundary conditions, or the fact that the perturbations should decay at infinity. Is there a way to fix this issue, or am I understanding something wrong? and if this is not the correct way to stablish the asymptotic behavior, how does one determine it?
Any help with this problem would be great!
EDIT: Some details about my calculations, I basically followed (reference) but with another tensor spherical harmonic basis. I wrote the perturbation in the most general form given by:
For even parity (polar part) perturbations the perturbed metric can be decomposed as
$$ h_{\mu \nu}^{even} = e^{-i \omega t} \begin{pmatrix}
            H_0 Y_{lm} & - H_1Y_{lm} & -r H_2 \partial_\theta Y_{lm} & -r H_2 \partial_\phi Y_{lm} \\
            \text{Sym} & H_4 Y_{lm} & r H_3 \partial_\theta Y_{lm} & r H_3  \partial_\phi Y_{lm} \\
            \text{Sym} & \text{Sym} & r^2 \left[ K + G \left( \partial_\theta^2 + \frac{1}{2}l(l+1) \right) \right] Y_{lm} & r^2 G \left[ \partial_\theta \partial_\phi - \cot \theta \partial_\phi \right] Y_{lm} \\
            \text{Sym} & \text{Sym} & \text{Sym} & r^2 \sin^2 \theta \left[ K - G \left(\partial_\theta^2 + \frac{1}{2}l (l+1) \right) \right] Y_{lm}
        \end{pmatrix}
    $$
And for the odd-parity (axial part) perturbations the perturbation can be written as
$$
        h_{\mu \nu}^{odd} = e^{-i \omega t}\begin{pmatrix}
            0 & 0 & r \csc \theta \  h_0 \partial_\phi Y_{lm} & -r \sin \theta \ h_0 \partial_\theta Y_{lm} \\
            0 & 0 & - r \csc \theta \ h_1 \partial_\phi Y_{lm} & r \sin \theta h_1 \partial_\theta Y_{lm} \\
            \text{Sym} & \text{Sym} & -r^2 \csc \theta \ h_2 \left[ \partial_\theta \partial_\phi - \cot \theta \partial_\phi \right] Y_{lm} & - \frac{r^2}{2}h_2 \left[ \csc \theta \partial^2_\phi + \cos \theta \partial_\theta - \sin \theta \partial^2_\theta \right] Y_{lm} \\
            \text{Sym} & \text{Sym} & \text{Sym} & r^2 h_2 \left[ \sin \theta \partial_\theta \partial_\phi - \cos \theta \partial_\phi \right] Y_{lm}
        \end{pmatrix}$$
Where the functions $H_1,H_2,H_3,H_4,G,K,h_0,h_1,h_2$ are arbitrary functions that depend only on the radial coordinate $r$. Then I expanded the linearized field equations in terms of these tensors. First I worked in the Regge-Wheeler gauge, which is given by setting $H_2 = H_3 = G = 0$ and $h_2 = 0$, solved the system of differential equations and found that $ H_4 = H_0$ and other relations for $H_1$ and $K$. In particular the function $H_4$ is equal to the solution of the differential equation written above multiplied by $r$, namely $H_4(r) = A r^{3/2} j_\ell (r \omega )$, which behaves as $\mathcal{O}(r)$ at infinity. ( $r \to \infty$)
For the odd equations I found something similar, the function $h_1$ is given by $h_1(r) = B \sqrt{r} j_\ell(r \omega)$, but since the components of the perturbation $h_{r \theta}, h_{r \phi}$ involves the term $r h_1(r)$ these components are also of order $\mathcal{O}(r)$ at infinity.
Finally to be sure that my results do were not gauge dependent, I computed the gauge invariants and wrote the linearized field equations in terms of them, solved the equations and found the same result as above.

How did you get that equation? What are your assumptions? Put in the details here please.

I expressed the perturbation in terms of the pure spin tensor harmonics, and assumed that the time dependence is given by $e^{i \omega t}$. Then I wrote the linearized field equations in the Regge-Wheeler gauge and got differential equations for the radial functions, in particular $h_{rr}$ satisfies what I mentioned above. I also found equations for the other components, for example that $h_{00} = h_{rr}$.
Then I repeated the calculations without fixing the gauge. I found the gauge invariants, and they satisfied the same equations.

Ya, put in all those details in the question. We can't answer your question without seeing all the calculations in detail.

I wrote some details above, but I basically followed the paper by Regge and Wheeler "Stability of a Schwarzschild Singularity", but considering the Minkowski metric as the background.

I don't see any extra equations, just words. What is $Q(r)$ in the metric? What is your metric ansatz? Put in all the details in the question.

I wrote the details, and explained what I did. As I mentioned above the component $h_{rr}$ is proportional to $r Q(r)$.

Perhaps someone with enough experience will come along and know the answer after one look at the question. In the meantime, my only question is whether you can be sure you didn't just make a calculation error. Do you have any reference you can compare? It can't be the first time someone does this calculation.

@Javier — That is exactly my thought. That's why I want the OP to write down the details of all calculations so we can see where they went wrong, if anywhere.

I don’t know what more details can I write without writing down all the computations. I did them using the “xAct” package of Mathematica, maybe I can share the notebook. Also I think they are correct since I got the same equation that one gets from the schwarzschild metric but setting $M=0$.

Well, it would be useful to compare to a reference, maybe the one that works out the perturbations in a Schwarzschild background, and see if they get the same result. But I'm only saying this because I'm not an expert (so I don't know the answer) and I don't feel like doing the math myself.

I found the answer about the question by reading the PhD thesis of C.V. Vishveshwara (link). My approach was wrong in the sense that I was only looking at each mode individually.
The idea is to find the equation for the radial functions, and if the solutions corresponding to the real frequencies (giving an oscillatory behavior in time $e^{- i \omega t}$) form a complete set, then one is able to build any well-behaved initial perturbation at $t=0$ that remains well-behaved in time.
Hence, I understand that one is able to set any boundary condition; however, from other physical conditions (for example a finite non-zero value of energy), one is able to determine which are the apropriate boundary conditions.
Finally, regarding my question, given that the solutions that I found are given by Bessel functions, which form a complete set only with real frequencies, the Minkowski background is stable to linear order.

You can find something about the
asymptotic behavior of the metric
here. It's
about the binomial expansion in the Lagrangian function that leads to a new metric tensor.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(1+{\frac{GM}{rc^{2}}}\right)^{-1}
&0&0&0
\\
0&-\left(1+{\frac {GM}{rc^{2}}}\right)&0&0
\\0&0&-r^{2}&0
\\0&0&0&-r^{2}\sin ^{2}\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
